# Java3D: JNI Error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/j3d/Canva s3D: Windows 7

Tags: java-8, java-3d, canvas3d

```
OS: Windows 7 64-bit
Java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202 [Installed jdk-8u202-windows-x64.exe]
Java 3d: C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.1 [Installed java3d-1_5_1-windows-amd64.exe]
Environment Varaibles:
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202
JRE_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre
PATH=%PATH%:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\Java3D\1.5.1\lib;

And also copied j3d jars[j3dcore.jar, j3dutils.jar and vecmath.jar] to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\ext. j3dcore-ogl.dll to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin
```

Running the classic HelloJava3D Program and getting the below error. I can understand this is looking for Canvas3d class but that already present in one of the java3d jar file. Have come across similar thread in stackoverflow where they mentioned to check the classpath.Above i've shared the path which i set. Anything i missed out?
[Java3D - Some classes not found but classpath is set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416254/java3d-some-classes-not-found-but-classpath-is-set-correctly)
But in my case its showing some JNI error is it because some architecture mismatch?

```
D:\JavaSample>java HelloJava3D
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/j3d/Canva
s3D
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

One of the tool in my project is dependent on Java3d and i'm from c++ background and new to this project. I couldn't figure out what i am missing. Please suggest.

Comment: So you decided to try to run prehistoric software in an ancient environment. If you try newer JDK versions, they will give you better diagnostics, like telling you whether a `ClassNotFoundException` was caused by an absent dependency. On the other hand, newer versions don’t have an `ext` folder anymore, so you’d have to place these jar on the class path then.

Comment: Please use a lot more recent version of Java3D, don't use the obsolete extension mechanism and follow the steps of my tutorial: http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/